# unicode in dictionary gives hex output

Tags: python

I have a dictionary (key, value) pair. The key is 'ASCII' (e.g. 'hello'), 
the value is not English (e.g. Chinese 輸入曲目).

Some code:

```
    t_t = {}
    s_0 = 'hello'
    s_v = '輸入曲目'
    print s_v       # gives the Chinese 輸入曲目
    t_t[s_0] = s_v

    print t_t.values()
```

The output is in hex (e.g. '\x39\xef')

Even accessing the value in code:

```
ss = t_t['hello']
print ss
```

gives me hex.

Since I am using this as a translator, I really need the unicode.

Running this via a 'DOS' console window on Windows 7.  Python version is 2.7.1

Comment: The output with `.values()` is expected and wanted. But there shouldn't be a difference between the first and the last. Are you sure you store just the string and not e.g. a list wrapping the string?

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to walk the values manually. The print is turning it in to hex because you're asking it to print the whole tuple, and print sees your string as arbitrary binary data. So as to not totally mess up some folks terminals, it encodes potentially unprintable characters as hex. The contents of the string isn't impacted -- it is only a product of how you're displaying it.

As an example:

```
for v in t_t.values():
    print v
```

This should print the expected values.

You should also consider using either Python 3 or Unicode strings (u"Unicode string"). What you have now isn't portable and is dependent upon your system encoding.

Comment: It's not really about "not messing up terminals", it's about `repr()` only printing printable ASCII characters so you can see what something actually contains, rather than what it prints as.

Comment: You are correct. Specifically, two Unicode character sequences can print as the same thing while being composed of different sequences. That aside, there is real value in not sending out control sequences (either in the C0 or C1 blocks) as depending on the terminal emulator the display can be put in a strange state. Without knowledge that a string is a Unicode string, it really is just arbitrary binary data. The behavior of repr() predates Unicode strings in Python when you had system encoded strings and arbitrary binary data and there was no way to tell the two apart.